# LayoutInflater.Factory onCreateView is not called with 22.1+ support library

Tags: android, factory, layout-inflater

Main problem that my `LayoutInflater.Factory` (code example below) calls `onCreateView` and works fine with 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'. But `onCreateView` is not called when i moved to 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0' or higher. I can't understand why?

```
//From many fragments i Call hintManager.inflate
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    layout = hintManager.inflate(inflater, R.layout.generate_code);

...

//here is HintManager method called from various fragments. 
public View inflate(LayoutInflater inflater, int layoutResourceId) {
    AttributeParser attributeParser = new AttributeParser();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = attributeParser.getLayoutInflater(inflater);

    final View v = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
    //here AttributeParserFactory#onCreateView should be called, but it fails with 22.1+ support lib, but works with 22.0
    attributeParser.setViewAttribute(v);
    return v;
} 

...

//example of factory, that works fine with 22.0 support lib
private Map<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> helpViewList;

private class AttributeParser {

    private AttributeParserFactory mFactory;

    private class AttributeParserFactory implements LayoutInflater.Factory{
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            String id = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "id");

            if(id != null){
                // String with the reference character "@", so we strip it to keep only the reference
                id = id.replace("@", "");

                TypedArray libraryStyledAttributeList = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Help);
                HashMap<Integer, String> libraryViewAttribute = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                int i = 0;

                for(int attribute : R.styleable.Help){
                    String attributeValue = null;
                    if (attribute == R.styleable.Help_arrow || attribute == R.styleable.Help_padding) {
                        attributeValue = String.valueOf(libraryStyledAttributeList.getInteger(i, 0));
                    }
                    else {
                        attributeValue = libraryStyledAttributeList.getString(i);
                    }

                    if(attributeValue != null)
                        libraryViewAttribute.put(attribute, attributeValue);

                    i++;
                }

                if(!libraryViewAttribute.isEmpty()) {
                    helpViewList.put(Integer.valueOf(id), libraryViewAttribute);
                }

                libraryStyledAttributeList.recycle();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

    public AttributeParser(){
        mFactory = new AttributeParserFactory();
    }

    public void clear() {
        helpViewList.clear();
    }

    public LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(inflater.getContext());
        layoutInflater.setFactory(mFactory);

        return layoutInflater;
    }

    public void setFactory(LayoutInflater inflater){
        inflater.cloneInContext(inflater.getContext()).setFactory(mFactory);
    }

    public void setViewAttribute(Activity activity) {
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> attribute : helpViewList.entrySet())
            if(activity.findViewById((Integer) attribute.getKey()) != null)
                activity.findViewById((Integer) attribute.getKey()).setTag(attribute.getValue());

    }

    public void setViewAttribute(View view) {
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> attribute : helpViewList.entrySet())
            if(view.findViewById((Integer) attribute.getKey()) != null)
                view.findViewById((Integer) attribute.getKey()).setTag(attribute.getValue());
    }

    public Map<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> getAttributeList() {
        return helpViewList;
    }

    public void setAttributeList(Map<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> attributeList) {
        helpViewList = attributeList;
    }

}
```

Comment: what is `cloneInContext` called for? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: To create a new LayoutInflater with an additional LayoutInflater.Factory for your own views, you can use cloneInContext(Context) to clone an existing ViewFactory, and then call setFactory(LayoutInflater.Factory) on it to include your Factory.

Comment: are you using fragments from support library? are you sure that Fragment#onCreateView was called?

Comment: yes, i'm using android.support.v4.app.Fragment; and Fragment#onCreateView is always called i place break point and can stop there with debuger.

Comment: fine, if you feel comfortable with a debugger did you try to step-in `final View v = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);` inside HintManager#inflate ?

Comment: when i try to debug and step into android class (for example LayoutInflater) it shows me (stops at) comments, anotations and random places that gives no information :(

Comment: you gotta have proper sources (the same version as buildToolsVersion)

Comment: buildTools are just 22.0.1 and 23.0.1, i want to use  'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1' but there is no buildTools 22.2 version. v23 requires remove deprecated apache headers, too much work for this change and I'm concentrating on LayoutInflater.Factory issue

Comment: `LayoutInflater.Factory` methods are called from `LayoutInflater` code so without debugging that code you will have hard time in fixing the issue...

Comment: Have you tried implementing LayoutInflater.Factory2 instead of LayoutInflater.Factory?

Comment: If you are trying to use the support library why are you not using `LayoutInflaterCompat` and `LayoutInflaterFactory` instead of `LayoutInflater.Factory`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited answer:**

To solve this problem we should use LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory that helps with LayoutInflater Factory in pre/post Lollipop.

This is example

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflaterCopy = inflater.cloneInContext(inflater.getContext());
    LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory(layoutInflaterCopy, new LayoutInflaterFactory() {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            String id = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "id");

            if(id != null){
                // String with the reference character "@", so we strip it to keep only the reference
                id = id.replace("@", "");

                TypedArray libraryStyledAttributeList = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Help);
                HashMap<Integer, String> libraryViewAttribute = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                int i = 0;

                for(int attribute : R.styleable.Help){
                    String attributeValue = null;
                    if (attribute == R.styleable.Help_arrow || attribute == R.styleable.Help_padding) {
                        attributeValue = String.valueOf(libraryStyledAttributeList.getInteger(i, 0));
                    }
                    else {
                        attributeValue = libraryStyledAttributeList.getString(i);
                    }

                    if(attributeValue != null)
                        libraryViewAttribute.put(attribute, attributeValue);

                    i++;
                }

                if(!libraryViewAttribute.isEmpty()) {
                    helpViewList.put(Integer.valueOf(id), libraryViewAttribute);
                }

                libraryStyledAttributeList.recycle();
            }
            return null;
        }
    });

    final View v = layoutInflaterCopy.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is obsolete for **AppCompat v23**, please check sources of `sdk\sources\android-23\android\support\v4\view\LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java` to see how `LayoutInflater.Factory` issue is worked around in `forceSetFactory2` method.